# How do you specify the locale/language for an NSFormatter that doesn't have a locale property?

Tags: ios, macos, nsformatter

There are a lot of specialized subclasses of NSFormatter:

```
CNContactFormatter
CNPostalAddressFormatter
DRMSFFormatter
MKDistanceFormatter
NSByteCountFormatter
NSDateComponentsFormatter
NSDateFormatter
NSDateIntervalFormatter
NSEnergyFormatter
NSLengthFormatter
NSMassFormatter
NSNumberFormatter
NSPersonNameComponentsFormatter
```

Most of us have used `NSNumberFormatter` and `NSDateFormatter`. Those have a locale property that lets you specify what locale to use when converting from strings to/from the "native" format the formatter supports. Some others like `NSDateComponentsFormatter` inherit their locale from one of their properties (`NSDateComponentsFormatter` uses the locale of the specified calendar, if any.)

Most of the others don't seem to have any way to specify a locale. The only way I can think of to get them to generate output in a specific language/locale is to set the system locale, get the output/convert a string to numeric format, and then set it back.

Is there a way to set the locale for formatters like `NSByteCountFormatter` that don't seem to offer a locale setting of any kind?

### Edit:

Since I wrote this question the names of a lot of the formatters above have changed. Most (all?) have lost their "NS" prefix.

Comment: Only 4 of those classes lack a `locale` (directly or indirectly). They are `NSByteCountFormatter`, `DRMSFFormatter`, `CNPostalAddressFormatter`, and `CNContactFormatter`

Comment: It seems very unlikely. If you walk through the implementation, `NSByteCountFormatter` uses an internal function `_NSLocalizedFileSizeDescription`, which relies heavily on `-[NSBundle localizedStringForKey:value:table:]` (calling into Foundation's bundle). There's nowhere to pass a locale into that. I would open a radar requesting a `numberFormatter` property for `NSByteCountFormatter` to match `NSEnergyFormatter`.

Comment: Note that the use of `NSNumberFormatter` is very inconsistent. For instance, `NSEnergyFormatter.unitStringFromJoules(_:usedUnit)` does not correctly localize based on the locale of the `NSNumberFormatter`. But `stringFromJoules` does.

Comment: @RobNapier why don't you post your "well, for some formatters you can't" comment as an answer so I can accept it? This question has remained unanswered for a good long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very unlikely. If you walk through the implementation (in Hopper), NSByteCountFormatter uses an internal function `_NSLocalizedFileSizeDescription`, which relies heavily on `-[NSBundle localizedStringForKey:value:table:]` (calling into Foundation's bundle). There's nowhere to pass a locale into that. I would open a radar requesting a numberFormatter property for NSByteCountFormatter to match NSEnergyFormatter.